# Adding Control character in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am new to xslt.I am trying to transform xml to csv using xslt.The csv file is seperated by SOH(ctrl a) character.I know that character is not allowed in xml.I m just trying to output text.Is there any way i can add the SOH character in xslt in the version 1.0.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243823/xsl-include-some-ascii-control-chars-when-method-text

Comment: in my scenario,there is no link with dot net framework.i am using xsltproc in unix.the source xml file i am getting is of version 1.0

Answer (score 0):

> i am using xsltproc

Unfortunately, the `libxslt` processor does not support XML 1.1., so this is not possible to accomplish with XSLT alone. I believe your only option is to output a placeholder string, then process the result with another application to replace the string with the control character.